# Is it possible to trigger dialogs or responses based on QnAMaker result

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker, bot-framework-composer

I am trying to define separate flows/triggers different message when I do not get any answer from the QnA apart from displaying 'Fallback Answer'.

**Attached is a sample design from Bot Framework Composer.**

[image: 1]

I am using Bot Framework Composer - v2.1.0 and QnAMaker dialog (Microsoft.QnAMakerDialog). Please refer to the attached screenshot.

Is there any property that holds the answer or entire response from QnAmaker - so that I can write a condition?

Appreciate any inputs/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a normal HTTP request to the qnamaker rest api knowledgebase and based on response of that HTTP request process the condition flow as per your need.

[image]